# El dominio no se queda al navegar mi pagina web

Tags: web, iis, hosting, dominio, ip

Supongamos que mi dominio es example.com, logro entrar a la pagina principal de la pagina web pero al momento de navegar a otra pagina en vez de ir a example.com/otrapagina esta cambiando a la ip publica, ejemplo: 0.0.0.0/otra pagina.

Estoy usando iis 10.

Comment: como estás navegando a otra página? si en la etiqueta a usas una uri completa, el comportamiento sería el que describes.

Comment: por enlaces a otras paginas, voy a verificar los enlaces, Gracias!